# What does the @ symbol do in javascript imports?

Tags: javascript

For example:

```
import Component from '@/components/component'
```

In the code I'm looking at it behaves like `../` going up one level in the directory relative to the file path, but I'd like to know more generally what it does. Unfortunately I can't find any documentation online due to the symbol searching problem.

Answer (score 286, accepted):

The meaning and structure of the module identifier depends on the *module loader* or *module bundler*. The module loader is not part of the ECMAScript spec. From a JavaScript language perspective, the module identifier is completely opaque. So it really depends on which module loader/bundler you are using.

You most likely have something like [babel-plugin-root-import](https://github.com/entwicklerstube/babel-plugin-root-import) in your webpack/babel config.

Basically it means *from the root of the project*.. it avoids having to write things like `import Component from '../../../../components/component'`

**Edit:** One reason it exists is because `import Component from 'components/component'` doesn't do that but instead search in the `node_modules` folder

Comment: Thanks @felix-kling for improve my answer. It is a much better explanation than "not a standard thing" :)

Comment: Great thanks, how about Node.js applications? like Express apps? Would something similar still be possible?

Comment: For those using Laravel, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53517385/1446611)

Comment: God damn, this is one of the many reason why I hate the modern web techs.
you need to learn so many things, I miss the era when I just need to write html + js + css
Take this for example, the module syntax comes from ES6, you learn it from somewhere, then you encounter this '@' thing, you will get confused as fk.

Answer (score 150):

Know it's old, but I wasn't exactly sure how it's defined, so looked it up, came by, dug a little deeper and finally found this in my [Vue-CLI](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) ([Vue.js](https://vuejs.org)) generated Webpack config

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
    '@': path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
    }
},
```

so it's an alias which in this case points to the root of vue-cli generated src directory of the project

**Update**: As correctly mentioned by @aderchox in the comments, this is a general Webpack feature and not limited to Vue

Comment: Is it possible to use something like this? `'@*': ['client/src/*']` where only the part **after** `@` is taken, so that I can do `import X from '@components/x` and it correctly tries to access `client/src/components/x`? TS + VSCode already allows that in this exact form in tsconfig.json, however webpack errors with `Can't resolve '@components/x' in 'client/src/'`. When I change it to your solution and the import paths to `import X from '@/components/x'` it immediately starts working, so the paths are otherwise correct.

Comment: @Qwerty No idea, don't know the @* thing didn't know it exists in VSCode, so can't help

Comment: I use this solution too and I'd like to emphasize that this is vue-agnostic and can be done in "any setup that uses Webpack". (because making vue.js a blue link in the answer might make some folks ignore this answer).

Comment: Your of course right @aderchox, thank you I added it to the answer to clarify 

Answer (score 45):

To make [Ben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42711271/327074) more comprehensive:

First you need to add `babel-plugin-root-import` in your `devDependencies` in `package.json` (If using `yarn`: `yarn add babel-plugin-root-import --dev`).
Then in your `.babelrc` add the following lines into `plugins` key:

```
"plugins": [
[
  "babel-plugin-root-import",
  {
    "rootPathPrefix": "@"
  }
]
]
```

Now, you can use `@`. For example:

**Instead of**

`import xx from '../../utils/somefile'`

**You Can**

`import xx from '@/utils/somefile'`

Comment: I added the plugin to my devdependencies but I have no .babelrc . I even created it in the root ,but still does not work? I just have babel.config.js

Answer (score 19):

As said above, this feature is not in JS by default. You have to use a babel plugin to enjoy it. And its job is simple. It allows you to specify a default root source for your JS files and helps you map your file imports to it.
To get started install through either npm:

```
npm install babel-plugin-root-import --save-dev
```

or

```
yarn add babel-plugin-root-import --dev
```

Create a `.babelrc` in the root of your app and configure these settings to your taste:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["babel-plugin-root-import", {
      "rootPathSuffix": "the-preferred/root/of-all-your/js/files",
      "rootPathPrefix": "@"
    }]
  ]
}
```

With the config above, you can simply import from that source like:

```
import Myfile from "@/Myfile"
```

without doing all this funky stuff:

```
"/../../../Myfile"
```

Note that you can also change the symbol to anything like `"~"` if that floats your boat.

Answer (score 14):

I am using VS code to build react native Apps.

What you need is:

1. create a **jsconfig.json** under root path of your App
   [image]

2. in your **jsconfig.json**, add the following code:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
      "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@core/*": ["src/core/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

basically like `"shortcut" : ["abs_path"]`

Comment: This does not answer the original question. However, this anwer is helpful for the correct configuration of VS Code when the @ symbol is used.

Answer (score 13):

In case you are using Typescript, you could achieve this by simply using your `tsconfig.json` like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    ...

    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@lib/*": ["app/lib/*"]
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`// @ is an alias to /src`

Inspired by Can Rau's answer I made a similar discovery in my `src/views/Home.vue` file. This file was created with the latest (July 2021, Ubuntu 20.04) versions: `npx @vue/cli create myfirstvue --default`.

I "*inferred*" it was `/src` but wanted to know why, because Ben's [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42711271/866333) said it would be the root of my project, which in fact is the parent, of `/src`.

Here is Home.vue:

```
...
<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue'
</script>
```

It is defined by [Vue Webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/9992f5a058c53f32b03d9a8743612188c04698af/template/build/webpack.base.conf.js#L27), which I learned from [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42753045/866333).

Answer (score 1):

It is a way of remapping module paths, not part of the ES itself, you have to use babel import feature.