# sass-loader on webpack in Asp.Net Core

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webpack, sass

I need help in connecting the style loader scss-loader

i try include sass-loader in webpack.config.js for

vue-component:

```
@import '@/styles/mixin.scss';
```

webpack.config.js:

```
....
    {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      'css-loader',
      'sass-loader'
    ]
  },
....
```

but have all times error

```
Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
undefined
^
  File to import not found or unreadable: src/styles/mixin.scss.
```

Any ideas how to cure this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44251999/2630078) help?

Comment: it's my fail, @import "src/styles/mixin.scss" not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in vue component imports module have path 'src/name.scss' change it and loader works