# NODE_PATH and absolute imports with Laravel Mix and React?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-mix

I'm trying to combine a React app into a Laravel project by putting my React code here: `MyLaravelProject/resources/assets/js`. I'd like to use [Laravel Mix](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/2.1/mixjs) to generate the React development build using `npm run dev`.

My `webpack.mix.js` file:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.react('resources/assets/js/index.js', 'public/js');
```

My `index.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Root from 'Root';
import App from 'components/App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Root>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path='/' component={App} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Root>,
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

My problem is that all of my React app files are dependent on a `.env` file that contains `NODE_PATH=js/` to enable [absolute imports](https://medium.com/@ktruong008/absolute-imports-with-create-react-app-4338fbca7e3d). I get this error when I run `npm run dev`:

```
ERROR in ./resources/assets/js/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'Root' in '/Users/MyUser/MyLaravelProject/resources/assets/js'
 @ ./resources/assets/js/index.js 4:0-24
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/index.js

ERROR in ./resources/assets/js/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'components/App' in '/Users/MyUser/MyLaravelProject/resources/assets/js'
 @ ./resources/assets/js/index.js 5:0-33
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/index.js
```

I can fix this error if I change my import statements to use relative paths, but this would be a headache to do this with all of my React files.

```
import Root from './Root;
import App from './components/App;
```

I have tried the following changes to `.env` to no avail:
1) `NODE_PATH=resources/assets/js/`
2) `NODE_PATH=./`
3) `MIX_NODE_PATH=resources/assets/js/`
4) `MIX_NODE_PATH=./`

I've also tried changing the `package.json` dev script by adding `NODE_PATH=./`.

None of those changes the error message, so my problem appears to be that the path I define in `webpack.mix.js` is both the starting React app file and the absolute path.

Do I need to change all of the paths in my React app files to relative paths or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the following works pretty well in my Laravel/React scenario.

Add this to your `webpack.mix.js` file

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
        alias: {
            "@": __dirname + "/resources/assets/js"
        }
    }
});
```

Now your imports become

```
import Root from '@/Root';
import App from '@/components/App';
```

Hope this helps.

Special thanks to [Kaz Gosho](https://dev.to/acro5piano/laravel-tips-set-resolve-alias-in-laravel-mix-6f5)

Comment: Can you describe how to use same thing with `create-react-ap` '@/components' thing.?