# Global CSS for Vue project using CLI3

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue Js project I'm building and created it with CLI3 but I'm not sure where I should be placing my global CSS file. There are a few answers out there but it's for older versions with folders that aren't there anymore.

Where should a css file go and where should I be importing it?

Comment: Place `.css` file anywhere you want and then in your `main.js` you can import it with `import '@/path/to/file/my-style.css'`.  Read more about `@` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711175/what-does-the-symbol-do-in-javascript-imports#comment72543541_42711175)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in `app.js`, and not in a `scoped` `script` element.
That is how the demo adds global `CSS`.

If it gets too big and unmanageable, import `css` files in app.js instead.