# Loading a local image with Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gatsby, gatsby-image

I am trying to create an "avatar" component using Gatsby with typescript. Thee component is supposed to use a local image. My component looks like

```
const avatar: React.FC<Props> = ({imageUrl, title}: Props) => (
    <div className="avatar" title={title} style={{backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})`}} />
);
```

And I am calling it with

`<Avatar title={"Avatar"} imageUrl={"../avatar/elements.png"} />`

The path to the file is correct, however it's not showing up. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Is there a way to make the image go through gatsby-image for being optimized?

Comment: Getting local images on gatsby is hard. Im struggling with a lot of gatsby things. You need to use graphQL to load the image into your component using a query, and then use that filename, instead of a hardcoded string. its complicated, have a look at https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/working-with-images/

Comment: This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56957020/203130

Comment: If you want to process images with Sharp for `gatsby-image`, you'll need to pull your local images into your GraphQL schema first. You'll want to use `gatsby-source-filesystem` for this. As suggested by @BenB, [Working with images in Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/working-with-images/) is a good place to start.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of the question linked by @coreyward