# Refactor aliased @ imports to relative paths

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, refactoring, jetbrains-ide, es6-modules

In modular environments that use Webpack, TypeScript or other tools that transform ES module imports, path aliases are used, a common convention is [@ for `src`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711175/what-does-the-symbol-do-in-javascript-imports).

It's a frequent problem for me to transform a project with aliased absolute paths:

*src/foo/bar/index.js*

```
import baz from '@/baz';
```

to relative paths:

*src/foo/bar/index.js*

```
import baz from '../../baz';
```

For instance, a project that uses aliases needs to be merged with another project that doesn't use aliases, configuring the latter to use aliases isn't an option due to style guide or other causes.

This cannot be solved with simple search and replace, and fixing import paths manually is tedious and prone to errors. I expect original JavaScript/TypeScript codebase to remain intact in other respects, so transforming it with a transpiler may be not an option.

I would like to achieve this kind of refactoring with IDE of my choice (Jetbrains IDEA/Webstorm/Phpstorm) but would accept a solution with any other IDE (VS Code) or plain Node.js.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Three possible solutions that rewire aliased imports to relative paths:

### 1. babel-plugin-module-resolver

Use [`babel-plugin-module-resolver`](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver), while leaving out other babel plugins/presets.

`.babelrc`:

```
"plugins": [
  [
    "module-resolver",
    {
      "alias": {
        "^@/(.+)": "./src/\\1"
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

Build step: `babel src --out-dir dist` (output in `dist`, won't modify in-place)

Processed example file:

```
// input                                // output
import { helloWorld } from "@/sub/b"    // import { helloWorld } from "./sub/b";
import "@/sub/b"                        // import "./sub/b";
export { helloWorld } from "@/sub/b"    // export { helloWorld } from "./sub/b";
export * from "@/sub/b"                 // export * from "./sub/b";
```

For TS, you will also need [`@babel/preset-typescript`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-typescript) and activate `.ts` extensions by `babel src --out-dir dist --extensions ".ts"`.

### 2. Codemod jscodeshift with Regex

All relevant import/export variants from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) should be supported. The algorithm is implemented like this:

1. Input: path aliases mapping in the form `alias -> resolved path` akin to TypeScript `tsconfig.json` `paths` or Webpack's `resolve.alias`:

```
const pathMapping = {
  "@": "./custom/app/path",
  ...
};
```

2. Iterate over all source files, e.g. traverse `src`:

```sh
jscodeshift -t scripts/jscodeshift.js src # use -d -p options for dry-run + stdout
# or for TS
jscodeshift --extensions=ts --parser=ts -t scripts/jscodeshift.js src
```

3. For each source file, find all import and export declarations

```
function transform(file, api) {
  const j = api.jscodeshift;
  const root = j(file.source);

  root.find(j.ImportDeclaration).forEach(replaceNodepathAliases);
  root.find(j.ExportAllDeclaration).forEach(replaceNodepathAliases);
  root
    .find(j.ExportNamedDeclaration, node => node.source !== null)
    .forEach(replaceNodepathAliases);
  return root.toSource();
 ...
};
```

`jscodeshift.js`:

```js
/**
 * Corresponds to tsconfig.json paths or webpack aliases
 * E.g. "@/app/store/AppStore" -> "./src/app/store/AppStore"
 */
const pathMapping = {
  "@": "./src",
  foo: "bar",
};

const replacePathAlias = require("./replace-path-alias");

module.exports = function transform(file, api) {
  const j = api.jscodeshift;
  const root = j(file.source);

  root.find(j.ImportDeclaration).forEach(replaceNodepathAliases);
  root.find(j.ExportAllDeclaration).forEach(replaceNodepathAliases);

  /**
   * Filter out normal module exports, like export function foo(){ ...}
   * Include export {a} from "mymodule" etc.
   */
  root
.find(j.ExportNamedDeclaration, (node) => node.source !== null)
.forEach(replaceNodepathAliases);

  return root.toSource();

  function replaceNodepathAliases(impExpDeclNodePath) {
impExpDeclNodePath.value.source.value = replacePathAlias(
  file.path,
  impExpDeclNodePath.value.source.value,
  pathMapping
);
  }
};
```

Further illustration:

```
import { AppStore } from "@/app/store/appStore-types"
```

creates following [AST](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/5d148d18ce5ccd86cd6aae8b65167111/76588f532a6c1d8e3c698879790ebffd476e0e6a), whose `source.value` of `ImportDeclaration` node can be modified:

[image: AST explorer]

4. For each path declaration, test for a Regex pattern that includes one of the path aliases.

5. Get the resolved path of the alias and convert as path relative to the current file's location (credit to @Reijo)

`replace-path-alias.js` (4. + 5.):

```js
const path = require("path");

function replacePathAlias(currentFilePath, importPath, pathMap) {
  // if windows env, convert backslashes to "/" first
  currentFilePath = path.posix.join(...currentFilePath.split(path.sep));

  const regex = createRegex(pathMap);
  return importPath.replace(regex, replacer);

  function replacer(_, alias, rest) {
const mappedImportPath = pathMap[alias] + rest;

// use path.posix to also create foward slashes on windows environment
let mappedImportPathRelative = path.posix.relative(
  path.dirname(currentFilePath),
  mappedImportPath
);
// append "./" to make it a relative import path
if (!mappedImportPathRelative.startsWith("../")) {
  mappedImportPathRelative = `./${mappedImportPathRelative}`;
}

logReplace(currentFilePath, mappedImportPathRelative);

return mappedImportPathRelative;
  }
}

function createRegex(pathMap) {
  const mapKeysStr = Object.keys(pathMap).reduce((acc, cur) => `${acc}|${cur}`);
  const regexStr = `^(${mapKeysStr})(.*)$`;
  return new RegExp(regexStr, "g");
}

const log = true;
function logReplace(currentFilePath, mappedImportPathRelative) {
  if (log)
console.log(
  "current processed file:",
  currentFilePath,
  "; Mapped import path relative to current file:",
  mappedImportPathRelative
);
}

module.exports = replacePathAlias;
```

### 3. Regex-only search and replace

Iterate throught all sources and apply a regex (not tested thoroughly):

```
^(import.*from\\s+["|'])(${aliasesKeys})(.*)(["|'])$
```

, where `${aliasesKeys}` contains path alias `"@"`. The new import path can be processed by modifying the 2nd and 3rd capture group (path mapping + resolving to a relative path).

This variant cannot deal with AST, hence might considered to be not as stable as jscodeshift.

Currently, the Regex only supports imports. Side effect imports in the form `import "module-name"` are excluded, with the benefit of going safer with search/replace.

Sample:

```js
const path = require("path");

// here sample file content of one file as hardcoded string for simplicity.
// For your project, read all files (e.g. "fs.readFile" in node.js)
// and foreach file replace content by the return string of replaceImportPathAliases function.
const fileContentSample = `
import { AppStore } from "@/app/store/appStore-types"
import { WidgetService } from "@/app/WidgetService"
import { AppStoreImpl } from "@/app/store/AppStoreImpl"
import { rootReducer } from "@/app/store/root-reducer"
export { appStoreFactory }
`;

// corresponds to tsconfig.json paths or webpack aliases
// e.g. "@/app/store/AppStoreImpl" -> "./custom/app/path/app/store/AppStoreImpl"
const pathMappingSample = {
  "@": "./src",
  foo: "bar"
};

const currentFilePathSample = "./src/sub/a.js";

function replaceImportPathAliases(currentFilePath, fileContent, pathMap) {
  const regex = createRegex(pathMap);
  return fileContent.replace(regex, replacer);

  function replacer(_, g1, aliasGrp, restPathGrp, g4) {
    const mappedImportPath = pathMap[aliasGrp] + restPathGrp;

    let mappedImportPathRelative = path.posix.relative(
      path.dirname(currentFilePath),
      mappedImportPath
    );
    // append "./" to make it a relative import path
    if (!mappedImportPathRelative.startsWith("../")) {
      mappedImportPathRelative = `./${mappedImportPathRelative}`;
    }
    return g1 + mappedImportPathRelative + g4;
  }
}

function createRegex(pathMap) {
  const mapKeysStr = Object.keys(pathMap).reduce((acc, cur) => `${acc}|${cur}`);
  const regexStr = `^(import.*from\\s+["|'])(${mapKeysStr})(.*)(["|'])$`;
  return new RegExp(regexStr, "gm");
}

console.log(
  replaceImportPathAliases(
    currentFilePathSample,
    fileContentSample,
    pathMappingSample
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks. My intention is get rid of `@` to make `@/` not appear anywhere in the codebase. *merging a project with another project* means that source files that previously were a separate project are copied into the project that doesn't assume the use of aliases.

Comment: I don't totally understand the babel option. It seems to be 100% better, does it overwrite your current files on disk? If so, we should add a note to make sure `git status` is clean (or just mention that source will be modified on disk). I'm probably mis-interpreting that answer...

Comment: So, this is actually modifying npm packages that have an @foo namespace (like @testing-library) https://cln.sh/hBuImC

Comment: I got some results by: 1. search replace all custom aliases to be some form of @root/foo/bar. 2. Running the jscodeshift script. However, I think it's ignoring all .jsx, .ts, and .tsx files. I'm not sure off hand how to accomodate these 3 other file extensions

Answer (score 15):

I created a script to do this.

It basically traverses the project tree, searches for all files, finds imports that look like "@/my/import" with a regex `/"@(\/\w+[\w\/.]+)"/gi` and than uses the [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_relative_from_to) module of nodejs to create the relative path.

I hope you don't have any edge cases that I didn't cover in this simple script, so better backup your files. I have only tested it in a simple scenario.

Here is the [code](https://gist.github.com/Stejnar/e03c79291de585b0d732b1e2d198d8aa):

```
const path = require("path");
const args = process.argv;

const rootName = args[2];
const rootPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), rootName);
const alias = "@";

if (!rootPath || !alias) return;

const { promisify } = require("util");
const fs = require("fs");

const readFileAsync = promisify(fs.readFile);
const readDirAsync = promisify(fs.readdir);
const writeFileAsync = promisify(fs.writeFile);
const statsAsync = promisify(fs.stat);

function testForAliasImport(file) {
  if (!file.content) return file;

  const regex = /"@(\/\w+[\w\/.]+)"/gi;

  let match,
    search = file.content;

  while ((match = regex.exec(search))) {
    const matchString = match[0];
    console.log(`found alias import ${matchString} in ${file.filepath}`);
    file.content = file.content.replace(
      matchString,
      aliasToRelative(file, matchString)
    );
    search = search.substring(match.index + matchString.length);
  }

  return file;
}

function aliasToRelative(file, importString) {
  let importPath = importString
    .replace(alias, "")
    .split('"')
    .join("");
  const hasExtension = !!path.parse(importString).ext;

  if (!hasExtension) {
    importPath += ".ext";
  }

  const filepath = file.filepath
    .replace(rootPath, "")
    .split("\\")
    .join("/");

  let relativeImport = path.posix.relative(path.dirname(filepath), importPath);

  if (!hasExtension) {
    relativeImport = relativeImport.replace(".ext", "");
  }

  if (!relativeImport.startsWith("../")) {
    relativeImport = "./" + relativeImport;
  }

  relativeImport = `"${relativeImport}"`;

  console.log(`replaced alias import ${importString} with ${relativeImport}`);
  return relativeImport;
}

async function writeFile(file) {
  if (!file || !file.content || !file.filepath) return file;
  try {
    console.log(`writing new contents to file ${file.filepath}...`);
    await writeFileAsync(file.filepath, file.content);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}

async function prepareFile(filepath) {
  const stat = await statsAsync(filepath);
  return { stat, filepath };
}

async function processFile(file) {
  if (file.stat.isFile()) {
    console.log(`reading file ${file.filepath}...`);
    file.content = await readFileAsync(file.filepath);
    file.content = file.content.toString();
  } else if (file.stat.isDirectory()) {
    console.log(`traversing dir ${file.filepath}...`);
    await traverseDir(file.filepath);
  }
  return file;
}

async function traverseDir(dirPath) {
  try {
    const filenames = await readDirAsync(dirPath);
    const filepaths = filenames.map(name => path.join(dirPath, name));
    const fileStats = await Promise.all(filepaths.map(prepareFile));
    const files = await Promise.all(fileStats.map(processFile));
    await Promise.all(files.map(testForAliasImport).map(writeFile));
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}


traverseDir(rootPath)
  .then(() => console.log("done"))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Be sure to provide a directory name as an argument. Like `src` for instance.

For the IDE part, I know that Jetbrains Webstorm let you define npm tasks. 
Create a `scripts` directory to hold the script. 
Define a script in the `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "replaceimports": "node scripts/script.js \"src\""
}
```

Register the npm task for usage in the npm tool window.

Comment: If you find this usefull please tell me, so I know it is worth to put more time into it.

Comment: Thank you, yes, it was useful. Please, list the code from the gist in the answer, it is supposed to be usable even if external links are off-line. I'll try to reward a second bounty to this post.

Comment: I used this script + the other jscodeshift script above. I then diffed and merged the results of the two. I actually used a slightly updated script someone commented on the linked github gist, which handles some specific details for running on mac. One great advantage of this script, it also updated jest.mock import paths, and even one path in some commented out code.

Answer (score 8):

A simple way to critically reduce the time spent on the task is to use regexp pattern matching to only target files located at a specific depth level. Assuming you have a magic path pointing to your `components` folder and a project structure like this:

```
...
├── package.json
└── src
    └── components
```

You can refactor it by a simple find and replace:

```
find: from "components
replace: from "../components
files to include: ./src/*/**.ts
```

Then you just go recursively:

```
find: from "components
replace: from "../../components
files to include: ./src/*/*/**.ts
```

I wrote a small blog post about this: https://dev.to/fes300/refactoring-absolute-paths-to-relative-ones-in-vscode-3iaj

Answer (score 2):

From the post you linked:

> The meaning and structure of the module identifier depends on the module loader or module bundler

Meaning, that there's never going to be a *one-size-fits-all* solution to this '@' -> relative imports conversion. What you *could* do is to have some program that lets you *specify* what the `@` means for a given project, and that should be a pretty decent solution!

I think the way I would go about this is to look at creating a [codemod](https://github.com/facebook/jscodeshift) that looks at files containing `@` in their import statements, and determines how many parent directories it has to traverse to reach a user determined *root* directory, then replace the `@` sign with an appropriate number of `../`.

Once you've made a codemod/program/script to do this, you can trigger it from your editor of choice!

This is at least how I would go about solving this (in addition to also looking around for premade solutions that I could apply before starting!)