# What the "@" stands for in paths like "@/assets/xyz"?

Tags: node.js, syntax, path

Sometimes I see paths written like "@/assets/XXX", and I reckon it refers to the root maybe (in Nodejs)? But i guess it's a syntax that doesn't apply everywhere because when I want to refer to the root folder and try to use it, it sometimes break. I am not sure the implications of it.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711175/what-does-the-symbol-do-in-javascript-imports#comment72543541_42711175

Answer (score 1):

The "@" is often used as an alias for a frequently used path (like src/) in webpack environments. You have to define it in your configuration file so the "@" can be resolved in the build-process.

If you work in an ES6 environment and import a component several times, it can be handy to create an alias for the component path.

---

Example (source: [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias)):

**resolve.alias**
object

Create aliases to import or require certain modules more easily. For example, to alias a bunch of commonly used src/ folders:

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      Utilities: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utilities/'),
      Templates: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/templates/')
    }
  }
};
```

Now, instead of using relative paths when importing like so:

```
import Utility from '../../utilities/utility';
```

you can use the alias:

```
import Utility from 'Utilities/utility';
```

---

You can find a similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42753045/10764912