# How to import maps module dependencies for react-svg-map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, npm

I'm starting to look at interactive maps and I found the project [react-svg-map](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg-map). I was following along on the example and I come across this issue:

```
import Taiwan from "@svg-maps/taiwan";
```

They said that they split the maps svg code into a separate repo. Down below on the page they say that we need to install it separately and then point to the specific map we want.

I imported these two packages

```
npm install --save react-svg-map
npm install --save svg-maps
```

But when I copied the code and ran `npm start` I got the following error:

> ```
> Module not found: Can't resolve '@svg-maps/taiwan' in 'C:\...'
> ```

What does the `@` mean in the import and how do I import the `svg-maps` package. Do I need to have a folder that called `svg-maps/taiwan` in the same folder as the `App.js` script? Or is this something completely difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They said it's now needed to install the maps from the `svg-maps` packages. For Taiwan, it's `@svg-maps/taiwan` as seen [in the documentation for it.](https://github.com/VictorCazanave/svg-maps/tree/master/packages/taiwan)

```
npm install --save @svg-maps/taiwan
```

The [`@` sign on npm just denotes scoped-packages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36667258/1218980), not to be confused with the [common alias used in various projects configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42711175/1218980).