# Can't convert my JSON file into a JS object

Tags: javascript, json

My JSON file looks like this:

```
{
  "branding": {
    "body": {
      "header_text_color": "#224466",
      "body_text_color": "##224466",
      "background_color": "#224466"
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

In my script I'm trying to import that file, and then to convert it into a JS object:

```
import templateConfigJSON from '@/config.json'
const templateConfig = JSON.parse(templateConfigJSON)
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Unexpected token u in JSON

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: smellz like undefined :) can you conselog templateconfig before parse ?

Comment: working fine for me https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-browser-6l6hc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It is already an object so I think no need to parse it, You could use it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) is used to convert a string containing JSON notation into a Javascript object. Since it's already a `.json` file, you don't need to `parse` it:

```
import templateConfigJSON from "@/config.json";
console.log(templateConfigJSON); //outputs object
```

Comment: I am not fully d'accord with the explanation "Since it's already a .json file, you don't need to parse it". Usually JSON files or strings require parsing to a JS-object. Here the `import` took care of parsing already. That's why I posted my answer to provide additional explanation 

Answer (score 0):

Might be a misconception of JavaScript `import` statement.
It's used to import files in JavaScript syntax.

The prefixed `@` in path is most likely *Webpack*'s `resolve.alias` which is a stand-in for your source folder. As such the [`@` alias is  configured by Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44251999) for example.

#### JSON import using a module loader

So when importing a JSON file like this using *Webpack* (as configured by Vue):

```js
import myObject from "@/myObject.json";
```

You can immediately and directly use it, like any other JavaScript object previously defined:

```js
const keys = Object.keys( myObject );
console.log( keys );
```

No parsing required, because this has already be done by `import`.

See also:
[How to import a JSON file in ECMAScript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34944099/5730279)

#### Loading JSON in vanilla JS

In plain vanilla JavaScript you have to load the JSON via `XMLHttpRequest` and parse it or jQuery offers convenient function:

```js
$.getJSON("test.json", function(json) {
    console.log(json);
    var myObject = JSON.parse(json);
});
```

See also:
[Loading local JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file)