# React Hook: how to use "@foo/bar" to import custom hooks?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a custom React Hooks, named `bar` at `foo` directory, and I import it with the way below:

```js
import * from "../../foo/bar";
```

and the question is, how can I do it with the way:

```js
import * from "@foo/bar";
```

to avoid find the directory boring.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711175/what-does-the-symbol-do-in-javascript-imports

Comment: There are several ways to achieve this, I personally use TSConfig `paths`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#paths