# What does @ mean while importing libraries in JavaScript? import '@library-name'

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules, es6-module-loader

For example:
`import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';`

What is the significance of the '@'?

I tried looking it up but the answers explained its usage as a pointer to the root directory. (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711175/what-does-the-symbol-do-in-javascript-imports).)

Comment: Did you read this about npm namespaces? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667258/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-at-prefix-on-npm-packages

Comment: @sinanspd no, I didn't come across that. Thanks! I get it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NPM packages are sometimes published under a "scope".

When used in package names, scopes are prefixed with `@`. So `drawer` in the `react-navigation` scope is published as `@react-navigation/drawer`.

See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/using-npm/scope for more information.