# What does a TypeScript import beginning with a # hashtag mean?

Tags: typescript

I see following TypeScript `import`:

```
import { URLS } from '#constants';
```

Which looks to be alternative for

```
import { URLS } from './constants';
```

What `#` symbol means in this context (if used at the beginning of the import) ?

Comment: [_"The meaning and structure of the module identifier depends on the module loader or module bundler."_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42711271/3001761) Without more information about the package that import is _in_, it's hard to say what specific module gets resolved.

Comment: @jonrsharpe figured it out. Was hidden in official TS docs here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/reference.html#packagejson-imports-and-self-name-imports

Answer (score 1):

After bit of digging digging figured out what `#` means.

See in official TypeScript docs:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/reference.html#packagejson-imports-and-self-name-imports

- **TypeScript will attempt to resolve import paths beginning with # through the the "imports" field of the nearest ancestor package.json of the importing file.**
- tsconfig must be using modern options for moduleResolution as `node16`, `nodenext`, or `bundler`, and `resolvePackageJsonImports`

So it's easy to use `#absolutePath` anywhere (in nested folders) in project and it would always resolve to absolute project path to file.
It can eliminate use of `alias` to make paths prefixed for absolute imports inside projects.